# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)\cdots(1+x^n)}{\left(1+x^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\right)^n}$

Tags: limits

I have written a sequence $$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)\cdots(1+x^n)$$ as $$\frac{(x^{n+1}-1)(x^n+1)}{x-1}$$

Now, the limit is $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x^{n+1}-1)(x^n+1)}{(x-1)\left(1+x^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\right)^n}$$

What to do next?

Comment: I think your rewrite is incorrect. You are saying that $(1+x)(1+x^2)...(1+x^{n-1}) = (x^{n+1}-1)(x-1)$. this is not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dividing both numerator and denominator by $x\cdot x^2\cdot \ldots\cdot x^n=x^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$ we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)...(1+x^n)}{\left(1+x^{
\frac{n+1}{2}}\right)^n}&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\ldots\left(1+\frac{1}{x^n}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{x^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}+1\right)^n}\\
&=\frac{(1+0)(1+0)\ldots(1+0)}{(0+1)^n}\\
&=1
\end{align*}